# bash command to extract all the values for a given key of a json file

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I have a json file like that:

```
{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value", ....}],"field4":"value4"}
```

I would like to extract from all the rows, just the value of the field2. So I'd like an output like that:

```
[{"field3":"value", ....}]
[{"field3":"value", ....}]
[{"field3":"value", ....}]
```

I'm wondering if sed or awk could be help in this case.
I tried with

```
sed -e 's/^.*"field2":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

but I got the same output of the starting file.

I tried also with

```
 grep -o '"field2": [^, }]*' people_test_1 | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

but the value was cut off

Comment: I would use a json parser. Check this great project: https://github.com/micha/jsawk (for example)

Comment: Use Perl and [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON).

Comment: [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: what would be the jq command to do that?

Comment: ok I managed to do it with jq like that: < file  jq '.field2' but now I get an output like:
http://pastebin.com/Lj0RwevM
I would like to have it flat into one line as it was before.

Comment: I'm not really used to `jq` and I'm not sure yet but, your expected output is actually a bit confusing. Is `field3` meant to be repeating? Also  `[{"field3":"value", ....}]` is found as a value of "field2". What would be the uniform condition to extract it? How about other values that aren't?

Comment: If it was useful you can +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Example:

```
echo '{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value","asd":1},{"field3":"value2","asd":2}],"field4":"value4"}' | jq '.field2[] | .["field3"]'
```

Produces

```
"value"
"value2
```

Answer (score 0):

in your specific case (base on this explicit format where content ins between `[{` and first and only `}]`)

```
sed -e 's/^.*\(\[{.*}\]\).*$/\1/' YourFile
```

on any other format (content of `....` contain this pattern or other, you must specify the possible content.

eventually you need the `--posix` option in addition of mandatory `-e` here

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a proper JSON parser. If you really want a oneliner on the command line, you can issue

```
echo -e "import json\nfor line in open('file', 'r'): print(json.loads(line)['field2'])" | python
```

or

```
python -c "exec(\"import json\nfor line in open('file', 'r'): print(json.loads(line)['field2'])\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this sed command

```
$-sed -r 's/[^[]+([^]]*.).*/\1/g' File_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file contains an array of objects like

```
[{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value" }],"field4":"value4"},
{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value" }],"field4":"value4"},
{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value" }],"field4":"value4"},
{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value" }],"field4":"value4"},
{"field1": "value","field2": [{"field3":"value" }],"field4":"value4"}]
```

the following [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command will produce the desired output:

```
jq '.[]|.field2' people_test_1
```